# How to handle Nullreference exception in windows 7 phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on coding4fun.fake call application.
A NullReferenceException occurs when I click on the button that calls LaunchApp_Click. In this application the application bar is taken and when i click on the appliction bar the null ecxeption occured.

Here is my code :

```
private void LaunchApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Settings.CustomizeSettings)
    {
        LoadRandomData();
    }
    else
    {
        // verify 
        // Settings.PhoneType = (Item)personPhoneType.SelectedItem;
    }
}
```

On this line `if (!Settings.CustomizeSettings)` the null exception occurs and it show CustomizeSettings showing null exception. In XAML the customisesetting is define in the property ISEnabled And datad binding is applied as shown
IN XAML:

```
<controls:PivotItem 
    Header="Person" 
    Name="person"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Settings.CustomizeSettings}" >
```

Comment: Please make your question readable and complete. Sorry, meanwhile done.

Answer (score 1):

**NullReferenceException** is thrown when you are trying to perform some operation on an ***object/field*** which is **NULL**. In this case if the Exception is thrown at

```
if(!Settings.CustomizeSettings)
{
}
```

then it means that either your *Setting* object or the *CustomiseSettings* property is **NULL**.
The simple approach to handle this is to put the

```
if(!Settings.CustomizeSettings)
{
}
```

inside **Try-Catch** block.

```
try
{
    if(!Settings.CustomizeSettings)
    {
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Handle the exception here.
}
```

or else you can just check either of them so that they are not **NULL** before actually using them.